# Resourse file (.resw) in UWP

Tags: uwp, resource-file

I have Universal Class Library (.dll) to share between projects. In the dll I have several resources `.resw`  files `dll\rootFolder\Lang\` `en.resw` , `fr.resw` , `jp.resw`.

In my app I have button **"Change Language"** clicking on which I want change app language like many web sites but the problem is that I can't get this files when clicking on the button using `Resources.ResourceLoader()`

Comment: Can you provide your code to help people understand what's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) As @DevidFarinelli said, it would be nice to edit your question and add the code you've written so far : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you haven't placed your resources in the right folders.
You should create a structure like this:
`strings\en\resources.resw`, `string\fr\resources.resw` etc...

Then you use the ResourceLoader to get access to your files and resources

```
ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("[assemblyname]/[resourceName]")
```

You can check the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationResources) for application resources as it demonstrates everything that you seem to require in your code.